# pdftex.def error when uploading in arXiv: PDF file not found

Tags: pdftex, overleaf, arxiv, epstopdf

I have the following problem: I am uploading on arXiv a .zip file (obtained through Overleaf) containing some files:

1. the main .tex file
2. the reference bibtex file
3. a folder 'figures' with some .eps figures and one .png figure.

When I try uploading, I receive some warnings and a **pdftex.def error**, saying that a .pdf file was not found. Since I do not have any .pdf file, I was wondering whether the package epstopdf that I have in the preamble might cause that problem (actually this is a template I used time ago). In particular, I have the following error:

```
    ! Package pdftex.def Error: File `figures/NMSE_GGM_piecewise_N18_T20000_gamma0d
    ot999_alpha0dot01000_beta0dot01000_initSamples100.pdf' not found: using draft s
    etting.
    
    See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
    Type H <return> for immediate help.

...

l.870 ...ha0dot01000_beta0dot01000_initSamples100}
%
?
! Emergency stop.
...

l.870 ...ha0dot01000_beta0dot01000_initSamples100}
%
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on bare_jrnl.log.

[verbose]: pdflatex 'bare_jrnl.tex' failed.
```

Comment: from the error it looks like you are including figures/NMSE_GGM_piecewise_N18_T20000_gamma0d
    ot999_alpha0dot01000_beta0dot01000_initSamples100.pdf not an eps, it is anyway better to use pdf if you are using pdftex, convert the eps to pdf locally and include the pdf in your upload

Comment: Should the epstopdf package do that automatically for me in local?

Comment: yes or just run `epstopdf file.eps`  and it will generate `file.pdf` (the automatic convertion makes files with names  `file-eps-coverted-to.pdf`  which is why I think your log isn't using automatic epstopdf

Comment: I had my project in Overleaf, so all the compilation was carried there. I did not use a local Tex version. Shall I do the conversion manually for all the images?

Comment: it's very hard to say as you have given no indication about your input: all you have shown so far is that pdftex is looking for a pdf file that you have not provided.  The pdf files will be in the generated files list in your overleaf project you can download  them from there, assuming you are using pdftex and not latex at overleaf

Comment: In overleaf I use pdfLatex to compile, but this does not generate any additional files in the browser. What I am doing is to download a .zip file from overleaf, which contains my .eps images, and trying to upload in arXiv, which raises the mentioned error.

Comment: pdftex can not include eps files so if it is working on overleaf it will have generated the pdf and left them in the same place as aux files and other generated files (not in your main project list)

Comment: Also: arXiv doesn't convert postscript figures to pdf automatically (which many local tex will, as will Overleaf), so you need to have the files in the format expected by your tex engine prior to submitting to arXiv. This is also covered in the [arXiv FAQ](https://arxiv.org/help/faq/mistakes#mixed).

Answer (score 3):

arXiv doesn't support a [mixed figure file](https://arxiv.org/help/faq/mistakes#mixed) environment, so you will need to either convert your postscript figures to a `pdflatex`-compatible format (pdf, jpg, png), or convert the singular png figure to use pdflatex.

Remember to update your figure file inclusion commands appropriately.